# Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1 in the datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter and data table. I am displaying the data in the list . If there is a record in the database then records are displaying but if there is no record in the table then I am getting the error "Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. "
I checked in network tab I am getting th `{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":["0"]}`

```
public function MembershipList(){
    $fetchclubfees = $this->Fees_model->MembershipList();

          $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
          $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
          $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

            $recordsTotal = count($fetchclubfees);
            $recordsFiltered = count($fetchclubfees);

            $data = array(); 
            $n=1;
            if(!empty($fetchclubfees)){
           foreach($fetchclubfees as $row)  
           {  
                $sub_array = array();
                $sub_array[] = $n++; 
                $sub_array[] = $row->a;  
                $sub_array[] = $row->b;
                $sub_array[] = $row->c;
                $sub_array[] = $row->d;  
                $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row->m_id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Edit</button>';  
                $data[] = $sub_array;  

           }  
            }
            else{
                $data[]="0";
            }
           $output = array(  
           "draw"   => $draw,  
            "recordsTotal" =>$recordsTotal,  
            "recordsFiltered"  =>$recordsFiltered, 
            "data" =>     $data  
           );  
           echo json_encode($output);  

  }
```

> DataTables warning: table id=Membershiplist - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

would you help me out on this issue?

Comment: you have set here   $data[]="0"; as zero what else do you want  ?

Comment: @ShaikhAzharAlam, I set  $data[]="0"; but still I am getting the error. i am getting in the network tab {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":["0"]}. Also I am getting the alert "DataTables warning: table id=Membershiplist - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. "

Comment: Why recordsTotal and recordsFiltered showing value 1? My array is totally empty

Comment: what does count($fetchclubfees); return ?

Comment: @ShaikhAzharAlam, I tried to print print_r($fetchclubfees) then I am getting the 0.

Comment: echo count($fetchclubfees); result  ??

Comment: @ShaikhAzharAlam, count($fetchclubfees); is displaying 1 and print_r($fetchclubfees)  is displaying 0. Now Why I am getting 1? any idea? because array I am getting 0

Comment: echo count(array_filter($fetchclubfees, 'strlen')); use this

Comment: I tried to     print_r(count(array_filter($fetchclubfees, 'strlen'))); also tried count(array_filter($fetchclubfees, 'strlen'));  and I got an error "Message: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186258/discussion-between-shaikh-azhar-alam-and-user9437856).